# how can $((\frac1N \sum z_i )- I )^2 = \frac1{N^2}(\sum (z_i - I)^2 )$?

Tags: probability, summation

$$\left(\left(\frac1N \sum z_i \right)- I \right)^2 = \frac1{N^2}\left(\sum (z_i - I)^2 \right)$$

How does this work? Or is there an error? I thought that you could not pull the sum out of the square?

Context is calculating $$Var\left(\frac1N \sum z_i - I\right)$$ for a Monte Carlo Estimator, where I is the desired value for the Estimator

Comment: What does $I$ denote?

Comment: in the context it is the mean, but for this transformation I treat it just as a variable

Comment: Do you mind if I change $I$ to $\bar{z}$? It is a better notation for the mean.

Comment: I would leave it like that because I is not exactly the mean, (I was a bit hasty and inexact with my response). This is part of a variance reduction for monte carlo methods, so I is not the mean but the Monte Carlo estimator of it

Comment: @user3688217 If that is the case then you should probably add that context to the question.

Comment: @Math1000 you are right, pulling the context out of it was what led to my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, my bad I found the solution and the short answer is that the two things do NOT equal each other

At first you multiply I by $\frac NN$ and use $\frac 1N$ to pull out the $\frac 1{N^2}$ of the square and then turn $N*I$ into a sum which you then combine with the other sum so you are left with:

$$\frac1{N^2}(\sum(z_i - I))^2$$

which you turn into

$$\frac1{N^2}(\sum_i^N(z_i - I)\sum_j^N(z_j - I))$$

or

$$\frac1{N^2}(\sum_{i,j}^N(z_i - I)(z_j - I))$$

This is as far as you can refactor it.

what made this possible in my case is that you had to calculate $$E[\frac1{N^2}(\sum_{i,j}^N(z_i - I)(z_j - I))]$$ and you can refactor that into $$\frac1{N^2}(\sum_{i,j}^NE[(z_i - I)]E[(z_j - I)])$$ which for all i,j where $i$ != $j$ is $0$ because $z_i$ and $z_j$ are independent samples so the covariance is 0

-> then the equality from the question is true